# Angular ng-repeat doesn't work with data fetched from mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new for web development. If it is a silly question, I apologize for it. My ng-repeat shows not thing with the JSON fetched from mongodb, but it works when I pass a local JSON. I've struggled for it the whole day. Could anyone tell me what went wrong?

here is my Angular code

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
  app.controller('CommentController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

//I've tried 'this.comment', it still not work.
//It works when I use a test local JSON'this.comment = [{Visitor: 123, Comment: 345, CreateDate: 879}, {Visitor: 123, Comment: 345, CreateDate: 879}]
    $scope.comment = 
    $http({url: 'db-comments'}).success(function (comments) {

//I've confirmed 'comments' is an array of the JSON objects which I want.

      return comments;
    });
  }]);
})();
```

here is my HTML code

```
<div id="home" class="container" ng-controller='CommentController as comments'>
  <div id="comment" ng-repeat="x in comments.comment">
    <h2>{{x.Visitor}}</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>{{x.Comment}}<p>
    <span>{{x.CreateDate}}</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my node.js code

```
router.get('/db-comments', function(req, res, next){
  Comment.find(function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log('can not fetch the data')
    }
    res.send(data);
  })
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed to you by scottseeker, you need to assign the http response data to your variable, not the promise.

However, because you are using the ***controller as*** syntax, that's not enough to make your example work. You need to set `this.comment` instead of `$scope.comment`. At first, you may want to write something like the following:

```
$http(...).success(function (comments) {
    this.comment = comments;  // don't write that
});
```

But be aware that the keyword `this` in a callback does not refer to the same *this* as outside. So if you use the *controller as* syntax, take the habit to write `var vm = this;` at the beginning of your controller, and set inside `vm` the variables you want to bind to the view (`vm` stands for *viewmodel*). Like that:

```
app.controller('CommentController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var vm = this;

    $http({url: 'db-comments'}).success(function (comments) {
        vm.comment = comments;
    });
}]);
```

As a side note, if you are not setting specific headers to your `$http` call, I'll suggest you use the short method `$http.get`. That's more readable:

```
$http.get('db-comments').success(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

$http returns a promise, set your scope variable in the 'then' portion.

Example:

```
       $http({url: 'db-comments'})
       then(function(response) {                    
          $scope.comment = response.data.
       }, function(response) {                  
          console.log('error: ' + response.error);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how the $http service works on AngularJS, but i would guess that it returns a promise right?

Altough i'm not very familiar with promises, i would suggest you to do it this way:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('CommentController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $http({
    url: 'db-comments'
  }).success(function(response) {

      // Bind the variable here
      $scope.comment = response.data;

    });
  }]);
})();
```

I hope this works for you, if not, let me know. Good luck!